# May I use cacao butter in place of coconut butter?

Tags: substitutions, butter

I'm out of coconut butter and am making fat bombs that call for coconut butter.  I have plenty of cacao butter on hand.  Can I use that instead?  Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what a fat bomb is, but coconut fats is pretty much all saturated fat. Cocoa gives about 50% saturated fat. So, they have pretty different properties overall.

Answer (score 4):

Not knowing your recipe (but I did some general googling re. fat bombs in general), I'd say go for it.

**The main differences are based on the higher melting point for cocoa butter**, which can actually make storage easier. At the same temperature, the cocoa butter based treats will be firmer - again a matter of taste.

But: The coconut oil based fat bombs will probably give you a "cooling" mouthfeel, caused by a combination of high enthalpy of fusion and a melting point below body temperature, it's the key ingredient in ["ice chocolate"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ischoklad). Cocoa butter with a melting point around 30-38C / 86-100F will not do that.

The taste will differ a bit as both fats have their specific taste, in combination with other ingredients neither should be overpowering, though.